# How do I attack in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mouse

I'm a noob at Skyrim and don't know how to attack.

It says press m1, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Hit left click to attack.

Comment: M1 = left mouse button

Comment: *slow clap* congrats

Comment: Just curious, what buttons have you tried pressing?

Comment: I wonder if he/she was pressing the M and 1 key simultaneously...

Answer (score 13):

M1 is the left mouse button. Click it to attack.

Have fun!

Comment: Related: M2 is the right mouse button, and M3 is the middle mouse button (usually the mouse wheel, which is clickable).